# posting in timeline doesn't post in ticker

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I tried posting something in my timeline via the following [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/). I can see it in my timeline, however it's not getting into my ticker. How do I do this? Do I need to have my action and objects approved first before I/my friends see this in their ticker?

Comment: I think the ticker, which I am assuming is the box on the upper right only shows posts from your friends

Comment: I did check from my friends ticker and it doesn't appear there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Step 6: Submit Your Actions For Approval](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#submit) (tutorial you refer to) only admins/developers/testers will be able to see actions before approval.

> Open Graph activity will be immediately visible to the administrators, developers and testers of your app. This allows you to do end-to-end testing of your integration. Once that is complete, submit your actions via the Dev App for review.
>
> After we have verified that your use of the Open Graph meets our criteria, we will approve your app to publish your actions to all Facebook users. Please note that we are not approving your app, just your use of the Open Graph Actions.
>
> See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/) for further details on the process.

Comment: even I have some people as testers in it, but I can't seem to get my post seen to ticker all the time, sometimes it's there and sometimes it's not